# Adjust css with jQuery

Tags: jquery, css

I need to adjust a tab link location when the browser gets below a certain width. I've looked around and haven't been able to make this work. It never readjusts. Here is the code I'm using

```
$(window).resize(
  function pageResize() {
  $screenSize = $(window).width();
  if($(screenSize) < 546){
    $("#ce").css("left", "80.5%");
    $("#ce").css("marginLeft", "-70px");
  }
});
```

Comment: Why not use media queries?

Comment: In the if statement instead of `$(screenSize)` use `$screenSize`.

Comment: The `if` condition should be `if($screenSize...)`

Comment: Please check if it even runs (as in if your function gets called and your if is stepped into) - you can do it either with breakpoints (in chrome) or by placing alerts or console.log. I think you cannot have a named function as an argument, but maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: This is a simple typo; closing the question as such.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a bug:

```
$screenSize = $(window).width();
    if($(screenSize) < 546){
```

You don't want `if ($(screenSize))` you want: `if ($screenSize)`.

Edit: and yes. Media queries makes WAAAAAY more sense than doing this with jQuery.

Comment: I got it. Thanks :) at first it wasn't working, but then I realized that my file wasn't named properly in the html file lol

Answer (score 0):

Almost :)
Try this:

```
$(window).resize(function () {
    $screenSize = $(window).width();
    if($screenSize < 546){
        $("#ce").css("left", "80.5%");
        $("#ce").css("marginLeft", "-70px");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I've also came across similar situation and here is the code I have implemented. I hope it will give you some idea.

```
$(document).ready(function () {   

        $(window).resize(function () {

            var navHeader = $('.header-container');

            var minHeight = 96;

            if (navHeader.height() > 90)
               minHeight = navHeader.height();

            $('.main-container').css('margin-top', minHeight + 10);
        });  

    });
```

If you are not seeing the expected result, check what values you are getting in $screenSize.